# Compute second derivative & minimising Runge phenomena (using Chebyshev nodes?)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differentiation

I'm trying to compute the second derivative of an array, although observe noise when using a spline fit and differentiating this, or when directly differentiating using np.gradient.

From reading about this topic, I believe that the Runge phenomena could be causing this noise. One suggested solution is unequal grid spacing - e.g. using Chebyshev nodes.

I couldn't see any functions like this built into Python so wondered if anyone had experience of this mathematical implementation in Python please?

Additionally, is it better to directly compute my array of values to differentiate on this new Chebyshev grid, or can I simply interpolate onto the new grid before differentiating to improve the accuracy?

Any tips or references most welcomed thanks.

Comment: Splines do not suffer from Runge, as they are piecewise low-order polynomials. So you can likely just use splines https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/interpolate.html#d-splines   If you are on the other hand doing polynomial fits, in addition to choosing the interpolation points e.g. as chebyshev nodes, the polynomial representation also needs to be a stable one, eg http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.polynomials.chebyshev.html

Comment: Thanks for this useful comment. Using splines does help, although strong noise is introduced when taking higher order derivatives. Downsampling the data beforehand seems to help, but I guess this isn't ideal. Are there any guidelines for minimising noise for spline differentiation? Thanks.